# How to update entire table using existing data in R?

Tags: r, datatable, data-manipulation

I have an established table in R.

| mail ct | 1 | 2 | 3 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1000 | 10 | 100 | 20 |
| 2000 | 200 | 100 | 30 |

I want to create a new table with the same column name and row number but different values based on the following calculation

| mail ct | 1 | 2 | 3 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1000 | 10/1000 | 100/1000 | 20/1000 |
| 2000 | 200/2000 | 100/2000 | 30/2000 |

The output should look like this...

| mail ct | 1 | 2 | 3 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1000 | 0.01 | 0.1 | 0.02 |
| 2000 | 0.1 | 0.05 | 0.015 |

How can I do it in R?

Answer (score 2):

Here's an approach using `dplyr`:

```
library(dplyr)
df1 %>%
  mutate(across(-mail.ct, ~.x/mail.ct))

#  mail.ct    1    2     3
#1    1000 0.01 0.10 0.020
#2    2000 0.10 0.05 0.015
```

This means: take `df1`, change all the columns except `mail.ct` to have them (".x") divide by that row's `mail.ct` value.

data

```
df1 <- data.frame(
  check.names = FALSE,
      mail.ct = c(1000L, 2000L),
          `1` = c(10L, 200L),
          `2` = c(100L, 100L),
          `3` = c(20L, 30L)
)
```

Answer (score 2):

You can do -

```
df[-1] <- df[-1]/df$mail.ct
df

#  mail.ct    1    2     3
#1    1000 0.01 0.10 0.020
#2    2000 0.10 0.05 0.015
```